# angular include component in loop

Tags: angular

Yes, I have posted few other questions and got few replies as well. Thanks a lot for your help. As I am new in Angular I asking one more question.

I have to develop a new application where my scren will look like the first screen. So I want to separate the screen in two different parts. One for Filter and other for Priorities which I want to put in a loop. Because I have to show N number of priorities as per database.

I need your suggestion (example code would be great) how to include the templates in my main template(i.e. iqsalert.component.html).

[image: The screen should like like]
[image: Break the top part (as Filter component) and Priority Component in a loop]

[image: Eclipse Folder structure]

Comment: Can you show the content of filter component and priority component?

Comment: @bugs: Currently there is nothing those components. I just put 
<div>
<B>Put Filter here...</B>
</div>

Comment: You include your own components the same way you include any other html elements. `<your-component></your-component>` Just make sure they are referenced correctly in app module.